# Unable to authenticate users using dual authentication in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I am implementing dual authentication in asp.net mvc 5,For internal users the authentication is happening through Azure AD.For external user there is login page to sign in .When a external user try to access the application ,it should be redirected to login page.

Where should i authenticate user & check if the user is internal or external user, Also please suggest where to specify the redirect url for login page ?

Below are the scenario i have tried based on some of the blogs.

I have created the customised attribute called ExternalAuthAttribute. I have inherited ActionFilterAttribute,IAuthenticationFilter.

I tried in both OnAuthentication & OnAuthenticationChallenge to redirect to login page. But it is not working. Please find below the code.

```
public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
        {

            var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
            if (user == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                //   filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                RedirectResult redirectResult = new 
                RedirectResult("Account/Login", true);
            }
}

 public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
        {

            var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
            if (user == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                   filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                RedirectResult redirectResult = new  RedirectResult("Account/Login", true);
            }
        }

*************Controller****************************
  [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {


        public AccountController()
        {
            _dataAccessor = dataAccessor;
        }
        [ExternalAuthAttribute]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
                return View("Login");
        }
    }
```

Output result,

IF user is internal user, login using Azure AD, if external user access the page, redirect to Login page.